Is there a way to count the number of reports on a server in SSRS?
I have a lot of reports on SSRS Server, is there a way to query count of all these reports on a specific server.
I didn't try anything as I couldn't find any related answer to my specific question.
Looking for help if it's possible.

On the report server database run the following query:
SELECT count(*) AS report_count
FROM dbo.Catalog
WHERE type = 2

This will give you the number of reports on the server

This worked. If for anyone in future it doesn't work, just include USE ReportServer; above
